# Cannot use xml2json in Ionic 3 : TypeError: exists is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 / angular 4 need to parse to JSON any XML, after 2 days of trying I'm now stuck in a TypeError: exists is not a function with no way of debugging it that I know off.

I already tried to reinstall xml2json, install the @type version, not sure if there is something wrong in my code, here is the error:

```
TypeError: exists is not a function
    at Function.getRoot (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:162940:7)
    at bindings (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:162819:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:183310:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:198811:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:198684:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:198675:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
```

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable }               from '@angular/core';
import { Http }            from '@angular/http';
import { ConstantsServices }        from './constants.service';
import { Xml2json }                 from 'xml2json';

@Injectable()
export class FinanzaService {
  private apiURL = this.constantsServices.apiUrl;


  constructor(public http: Http, private constantsServices: ConstantsServices) {
  }

// Obtengo datos del XML del mef-app eggds balance fiscal GC y SPNF

 public getBalances() {
  return this.http.get(`https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml`).map(res => JSON.parse(Xml2json(res.text(),'  ')))
  /*.map(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return [].concat.apply([], data);
  })*/;
  }
}
```

**TS file:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FinanzaService } from '../../services/finanzapublica.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'balances-home',
  templateUrl: 'balances.html'
})

export class BalancesPage {

  public titlePage: string = 'Balance Fiscal';
  public loader: any;
  public dataRequest: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public finanzaService: FinanzaService) {



  }
    callService() {
      this.finanzaService.getBalances().subscribe(
        (companies) => {
          console.log(companies);
          //this.companies = companies.list.Company;
          //console.log(this.companies);
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: Hi Michael, can you show us the error? Did you try to look into what `Xml2Json` method is returning back? Did you try to add a try/catch? Good luck!

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just edited and added the error. No sorry I don't know about try/catch

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce your error and never used xml2json. Instead I did use `xml2js`. You can find the npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js), hope you will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would to convert your Observable into a Promise.  You'd want to wait until the ENTIRE XML is completed, so you have a valid XML-DOC.  Then (.then ) use the xml2json method to convert the doc into a json doc.

I believe when you are using a Observable you're trying to convert the doc when not all of the elements have been returned so it would result in an error.  An invalid XML DOM is causing the wrong datatype to register with javascript which removes some available methods.

Comment: Hello buddy,  I tried to convert to Promise but it sends me an error using the "return", it states that it does not recognize that command